# jinja2 url_for multiple arguements jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got ':'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am getting parsing error  when I am trying to pass multiple arguments from jinja template:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got ':'

```
@classmethod
def follow_user(cls, followed_email, follower_email):
    with CursorFromConnectionFromPool() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO connections(follower_id, followee_id) VALUES (%s, %s)',
                           (follower_email,followed_email))
@classmethod
def unfollow_user(cls, followed_email, follower_email):
    with CursorFromConnectionFromPool() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("DELETE from connections WHERE follower_id = '{}' AND followee_id = '{}' ",
                           (follower_email, followed_email))
```

```html
{% if is_following %}
 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url_for('user.unfollow_user',followed_email:followed.email,follower_email:follower_email) }}" role="button">Unfollow</a>
 {% else %}
 <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{url_for('user.follow_user',followed_email:followed.email,follower_email:follower_email) }}" role="button">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url_for('user.unfollow_user',followed_email:followed.email,follower_email:follower_email) }}" role="button">Unfollow</a>
```

should be replaced with :

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url_for('user.unfollow_user',followed_email=followed.email,follower_email=follower_email) }}" role="button">Unfollow</a>
```

and using same '=' in the second line also :

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{url_for('user.follow_user',followed_email=followed.email,follower_email=follower_email) }}" role="button">Follow</a>
```

When passing arguments to parameters in `url_for` you should use `=`.